# Group theory exercise: proof that $b^2 = e$ if $|a|$ is odd and $b = a^{-1}b^{-1}a$

Tags: group-theory

> Please could someone help me with the last step in this exercise?

I've been stuck. The exercise is this:

Let $a,b$ be two elements in a group such that $a$ has odd order and $b = a^{-1}b^{-1}a$. Show that $b^2 = e$.

What I tried:

First of all let's assume that $|a|=2n + 1$ for some $n$. To show the claim one can  show $b=b^{-1}$. Let's try this:

$$ b = a^{(2n + 1)}ba^{-(2n + 1)} = a^{2n}b^{-1}a^{-2n} = a^{-1}b^{-1}a$$

But this is just the same as the assumption.

I feel like I'm this close but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$b^{-1}=(a^{-1}b^{-1}a)^{-1}=a^{-1}ba.$$
You should continue your argument, killing one $a$ at a time:
$$\begin{aligned}b&=a^{(-2n+1)}ba^{(2n+1)} \\&=a^{-2n}b^{-1}a^{2n}\\&=a^{-(2n-1)}ba^{(2n-1)}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=a^{-0}b^{-1}a^{0}=b^{-1}.\end{aligned}$$

---

Another argument based on automorphism group:

The conjugation $c_a(g)=a^{-1}ga$ is an automorphism of $\langle b\rangle$. Obviously $(c_a)^{2n+1}=c_{a^{2n+1}}=id$, where $2n+1$ is the order of $a$.

On the other hand $c_a(b)=b^{-1}$, so $(c_a)^2$ is the identity on $\langle b\rangle$.

Thus, on $\langle b\rangle$, $c_a=(c_a)^{2n+1}$ is also the identity homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the relation as $a=bab$.  Substitute this into itself and you get $a=b^kab^k=bab$ for all $k\ge 1$.

Now, suppose $|a|=2n+1$ and $|b|=m$.  We have
$$e=a^{2n+1}=\underbrace{(bab)(bab)\cdots (bab)}_{2n+1}=$$
$$=(bab)(b^{m-1}ab^{m-1})(bab)(b^{m-1}ab^{m-1})(bab)\cdots (b^{m-1}ab^{m-1})(bab)=ba^{2n+1}b=b^2$$
Note that we need $|a|$ to be odd because it is only every other $bab$ term we are turning into $b^{m-1}ab^{m-1}$.

Comment: what if $b$ does not have a finite order?

Comment: Then this doesn't work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First notice that : $b = a^{-1}b^{-1}a \Leftrightarrow a = bab .$

Thus

$$ba = babb^{-1} = ab^{-1}.$$

and

$$ ab = b^{-1}bab = b^{-1}a = a^{-1}ab^{-1}a = a^{-1}baa = a^{-1}ba^2.$$

Let $|a| = 2n+1$, then

$$ b = a^{2n+1} b = a^{2n}(ab) = a^{2n}a^{-1}ba^2 = a^{2n-1}ba^2 = \cdots =  aba^{2n} = b^{-1}baba^{2n} = b^{-1}a^{2n+1} = b^{-1}$$

which means

$$ b^2 = e .$$

---

A simpler way:

First notice that : $b = a^{-1}b^{-1}a \Leftrightarrow a = bab .$

Thus 
$$ a^2 b^{-1} = a(bab)b^{-1} = aba = b^{-1}baba = b^{-1}(bab)a = b^{-1}a^2. $$

So $b^{-1}$ commute with $a^2$, which means that $b$ commutes with $a^{-2}$ thus all $a^{-2k}$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $|a| = 2n + 1$, then $a = a^{-2n}$. So $b$ commutes with $a$. So

$$a = bab = ab^2 $$

and finally

$$ b^2 = e.$$

Answer (score 1):

$b=a^{-1}b^{-1}a$ (i.e. $a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}$), conjugate by $a$ both sides: 
$$a^{-1}ba=a^{-2}b^{-1}a^2 \Longrightarrow b^{-1}=a^{-2}b^{-1}a^2.$$
So $a^2$ commutes with $b^{-1}$, hence $\langle a^2\rangle=\langle a\rangle$ commutes with $b^{-1}$ (since $2\nmid o(a)$).

Then what does this implies *if $a$ commutes with $b^{-1}$*
 in your question?