# Follow up on when it happens that $b=b^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

This is a question that came up after my [previous question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536427/group-theory-exercise-proof-that-b2-e-if-a-is-odd-and-b-a-1b-1).

In my previous question I asked for help to prove that if $a$ is a group element of odd order and $b$ an element such that $b = a b^{-1}a^{-1}$ then $b^2 =e$.

Then I tried to understand when it happens that $b = b^{-1}$ and I tried to make a general statement.

In this case we found an element of odd order so that $b$ and $b^{-1}$ are conjugate and then it followed that they are in fact equal.

But it seems plausible to me that whenever $b$ and $b^{-1}$ are conjugate then one should be able to say more about $b$ or $b^{-1}$.

> Is there a theorem about what holds true when $b$ and $b^{-1}$ are
>   conjugate? Or perhaps a similar statement along these lines?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing an example of a (non-abelian finite) group for which $b$ and $b^{-1}$ are *not* conjugate

Comment: Apparently $A_4$ is a good example for that

Comment: @Omnomnomnom alternatively, if $|G|$ is odd, then no non-identity element is conjugate to its transpose. Since $|G|$ is odd, there can be no elements of order $2$, and if $x, x^{-1}\in C(x)$ for some $x$, then for any $y\in C(x)$, $y^{-1} \in C(x)$, meaning that the order of $C(x)$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

This has to to with *real* conjugacy classes, and also ambivalent groups (A group is said to be *ambivalent* if every element is conjugate to its inverse). See for example [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Ambivalent_group). Of course every $S_n$ is ambivalent. But not all $A_n$ are ambivalent.